# How to nest grid into grid in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have some trouble with listview in Xamarin. I'm making android application, where i have list of structures. In structure there is field auto_num (the number of a car), by which i must group all elements of list and i must make one cell for all other rows where auto_num field has the same value. Such as at photo below:[image]

> How i can do it? Here is my XAML:

```
        <ListView x:Name="deicerList" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Antiicing}">
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid x:Name="deicingGrid">
                    <Label Text="TYPE" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="17" ></Label>
                    <Label Text="QUANTITY" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="17"></Label>
                    <Label Text="REFRACT INDEX" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="17"></Label>
                    <Label Text="LABORATORY NO" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="17"></Label>
                    <Label Text="AUTO NO" Grid.Column="4" FontSize="17"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                                <Grid x:Name="deicingGridParent" >
                                    <Entry Text="{Binding type}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="17" ></Entry>
                                    <Entry Text="{Binding quantity}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="17"></Entry>
                                    <Entry Text="{Binding rri}" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="17"></Entry>
                                    <Entry Text="{Binding analisys_number}" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="17"></Entry>
                                    <Entry Text="{Binding auto_num}" Grid.Column="4" FontSize="17"></Entry>
                                </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's hard with Xamarin Forms... You can try to use GropuHeader and "Group" your items using auto_num field

There is a [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/ListView/Grouping/) on Xamarin documentation.

The XAML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="GroupingSampleListView.GroupedListXaml">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name ="lstView" IsGroupingEnabled="true" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding LongName}" GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate><TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail = "{Binding Comment}" /></DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The CodeBehind

```
public partial class GroupedListXaml : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<GroupedVeggieModel> grouped { get; set; }
    public GroupedListXaml ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        grouped = new ObservableCollection<GroupedVeggieModel> ();
        var veggieGroup = new GroupedVeggieModel () { LongName = "vegetables", ShortName="v" };
        var fruitGroup = new GroupedVeggieModel () { LongName = "fruit", ShortName = "f" };
        veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "celery", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "try ants on a log" });
        veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "tomato", IsReallyAVeggie = false, Comment = "pairs well with basil" });
        veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "zucchini", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "zucchini bread > bannana bread" });
        veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "peas", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "like peas in a pod" });
        fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "banana", IsReallyAVeggie = false,Comment = "available in chip form factor"});
        fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "strawberry", IsReallyAVeggie = false,Comment = "spring plant"});
        fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "cherry", IsReallyAVeggie = false,Comment = "topper for icecream"});
        grouped.Add (veggieGroup); grouped.Add (fruitGroup);
        lstView.ItemsSource = grouped;
    }
}
```

The "CODE"

```
namespace GroupingSampleListView
{
    public class GroupedListCode : ContentPage
    {
        private ObservableCollection<GroupedVeggieModel> grouped { get; set; }

        public GroupedListCode ()
        {
            var lstView = new ListView ();
            grouped = new ObservableCollection<GroupedVeggieModel> ();
            var veggieGroup = new GroupedVeggieModel () { LongName = "vegetables", ShortName="v" };
            var fruitGroup = new GroupedVeggieModel () { LongName = "fruit", ShortName = "f" };
            veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "celery", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "try ants on a log" });
            veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "tomato", IsReallyAVeggie = false, Comment = "pairs well with basil" });
            veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "zucchini", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "zucchini bread > bannana bread" });
            veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "peas", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "like peas in a pod" });
            fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "banana", IsReallyAVeggie = false,Comment = "available in chip form factor"});
            fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "strawberry", IsReallyAVeggie = false,Comment = "spring plant"});
            fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "cherry", IsReallyAVeggie = false,Comment = "topper for icecream"});

            grouped.Add (veggieGroup); 
            grouped.Add (fruitGroup);

            lstView.ItemsSource = grouped;
            lstView.IsGroupingEnabled = true;
            lstView.GroupDisplayBinding = new Binding ("LongName");
            lstView.GroupShortNameBinding = new Binding ("ShortName");

            lstView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(TextCell));
            lstView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding (TextCell.TextProperty, "Name");
//          lstView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding (TextCell.DetailProperty, "Comment");
            Content = lstView;
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel

```
public class VeggieModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public bool IsReallyAVeggie { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public VeggieModel ()
    {
    }
}

public class GroupedVeggieModel : ObservableCollection<VeggieModel>
{
    public string LongName { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Editable? Opening a Entry control on GroupHeader?

Comment: Such as at foregoing photo

Comment: I must merge auto_num cells in red border as one cell on interface

Comment: I think you can define your GroupTemplate so when you click on it you can popup an entry and modify the value...

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate/